# Is it possible to move this div by using transition like this?

Tags: html, css

```css
* {margin: 0;}
 
  div {background-color:pink;
   height:200px;
   width: 200px;
   margin: 50px auto;
   position:relative;
   transition: transform 2s;
   }


  p {
   text-transform: uppercase;
  }

  div:hover {
   transform: translate(200px 200px);
  }
```

```html
 <div><p>This is  text</p></div>
```

Hello , I've been trying to move this div to the right side 200px and to the bottom by 400px  when it is hovered. But it doesn't seem to work for me. I've already tried transition: transform 2s , and transition:translate 2s . But none of them seems to work. Is there any way to move it , or alternative ways? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Voting to Close as this question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.

Answer (score -1):

You need to add a comma between your translate values.

```css
* {margin: 0;}
 
div {
  background-color:pink;
  height:200px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  position:relative;
  transition: transform 2s;
  }


p {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

div:hover {
  transform: translate(200px, 200px);
}
```

```html
<div><p>This is  text</p></div>
```

Comment: better avoid answering to simply say 'you are missing a comma' even it's true, we should flag/close the question as a "typo error"